# Interpretation of $\frac{1}{r}\left(\frac{\partial V_\phi}{\partial x^\theta}-\frac{\partial V_\theta}{\partial x^\phi}\right)$ for given Space-time

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, general-relativity

I'm doing an exercise where I needed to find, for an arbitary $4$-vector $V^\mu$
$$ V_{r;\theta;\phi}-V_{r;\phi;\theta}=\  ???$$
for the space-time metric
$$ ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}=\left(1-\frac{r_g}{r}\right)c^2dt^2-\left(1+\frac{r_g}{r}\right)dr^2-r^2g_\Omega $$
Note that here $;$ denote the covariant differential so that
$$V_{r;\theta;\phi}=\frac{D }{Dx^\phi}\left(\frac{D V_r}{Dx^\theta}\right)$$

I'm able to show that the required quantity turn out to be

$$V_{r;\theta;\phi}-V_{r;\phi;\theta}=\frac{1}{r}\left(\frac{\partial V_\phi}{\partial x^\theta}-\frac{\partial V_\theta}{\partial x^\phi}\right)$$

It's asked to interpret this result which I'm not able to do. I can understand that the right-hand side is a radial component of the curl. But I'm not able to see any geometrical interpretation of why this should be equal to left-hand side. Please help me with this.